# Matlab eval function

Tags: matlab

I have to create a function of type:

```
myfunc( inp1, inp2, inp3) where inp1 is string/char and inp2 and inp3 are doubles.
```

so, an example call to above function will be like:

```
myfunc( 'USA', 13, 25)
```

The above example call will be generated during run time based on various conditions and I will need to perform the evaluation after that.

```
myfunc_implementable = "myfunc( 'USA', 13, 25)";
output(1) = eval(myfunc_implementable);

myfunc_implementable = "myfunc( 'America', 113, 125)";
output(2) = eval(myfunc_implementable);
```

How do I achieve the above? Because Matlab doesn't let me use the "" (double quotes).

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `eval` you should prefer [function handles](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/function-handles.html):

```
myfunc_implementable = @() myfunc('USA', 13, 25);
...
output(1) = myfunc_implementable();

myfunc_implementable = @() myfunc('America', 113, 125);
...
output(2) = myfunc_implementable();
```

You could also collect your arguments in a cell and call the function using `feval`:

```
func1 = @myfunc;
args1 = {'USA', 13, 25};
...
output(1) = feval(func1, args1{:});
```

If you really want to use `eval` for some reason, just write two consecutive single quotes inside a string as an escape sequence for one single quote:

```
>> myfunc_implementable = 'myfunc(''USA'', 13, 25);';
>> disp(myfunc_implementable);
myfunc('USA', 13, 25);
```